# Trying to identify a component in a 12 volt LED on/off touch switch

Tags: switches, identification, touch

I'm wondering if anyone can help me identify what this 8 pin IC is, in a capacitive on/off touch switch I have.  It is a soic or 8-VSSOP package.  64RX-Y is written on the bottom of the IC, nothing on top.  I can't find anything if I google that.  Pin 3 is connected to the touch input, pin 5 is connected to +5 volts from a regulator, pin 8 is connected to the gate on an N channel mosfet, and pin 6 is connected to ground.  I've searched for led drivers and flip flop ICs, but nothing seems to match this pinout.

I want to recreate this circuit because it works really well when connected to a steel lamp body that is powder coated, and turns the 12 volt LEDs on and off nicely.  I need to make a circuit board that is narrower and longer than this one though, so it'll fit in my lamp.

Attached is a schematic/layout diagram.  The mystery IC is in red.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: look for the schematic diagram of that circuit ...  maybe it indicates what the component actually is

Comment: Tontek has some capacitive touch chips whose pinout is promising, such as the TTP224B-RO8N. Ground on pin6, output on 8, Vcc on 4 all match. Perhaps worth investigating.

Comment: jsotola - I've tried looking for a schematic, can't seem to find anything like this one.

Unimportant - Thanks for the lead.  I'll look into those.  I'll report back if one of those works.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a clock crystal/piezo 64_x_hz, hince 64RX, to control/regulate a rapid AC output or prevent resonant feedback, also it appears to have some transistor or relay functionality because of the multiple pinouts. Most Y crystals have only 2 pins. But with the mosfets it could be used to modulate frequency as in pwm, useful for boosting voltage and amperage for bldc motors but potentially damaging to an LED or charging circuit (ie. overdrive prevention) look into these kinds of boards to see if you find anything similar used. It could lead to the answer you're looking for.